# typescript compiler does not recognize files in some folders

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

typescript compiler does not recognize files in some folders.

so the structure of my project is like this

1. client

   - src

     - App.vue
     - main.ts
   - package.json
   - tsconfig.app.json
   - tsconfig.json
   - tsconfig.node.json
   - vite.config.ts
2. server

when im doing 'import App from "@/App.vue";' inside main.ts im getting this ts error:

```
Cannot find module '@/App.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

when i do this its ok (but without the .ts extension, otherwise it shows error.)

```
import Boot from "@/services/AppBoot";
```

this is my tsconfig.app.json file:

```
{
"extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
"include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
"exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*", "dist", "node_modules"],
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "ignoreDeprecations": "5.0",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
}}
```

this is my vite.config.ts

```
import VueI18nPlugin from "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import vueJsx from "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx";
import { dirname, resolve } from "node:path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url";
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: true,
        port: 3000,
    },
test: {
    environment: "happy-dom",
    globals: true,
},
plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx(),
    VueI18nPlugin({
        include: resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), "./src/services/i18n/locales/**"),
    }),
],
resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".json", ".vue", ".scss", ".css"],
    alias: {
        "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
        img: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/img"),
    },
},
build: {
    sourcemap: false,
    minify: true,
    assetsDir: "chunks",
},
css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
            additionalData: `@use "sass:math"; @import "@/assets/scss/variables.scss";`,
        },
    },
},});
```

it happens in some other places but this was the easiest example to show.
the code runs, but the compiler shows error.

any idea what im missing?
why the compiler shows error?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems like you are missing `declare module "*.vue" {...}` shim. Look into a template Vue project to see how it looks like.